# CocoaAsyncSocket Index out of range on data object in Swift iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, indexoutofrangeexception, cocoaasyncsocket

One of my users receives occasionally a strange index-out-of-range exception.

This happens in the udpSocket callback of the CocoaAsyncSocket library.

```
func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data, withFilterContext filterContext: Any?)
    {
        idleTimer?.invalidate()
        
        nmeaStatus = .connected
        
        guard data.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        
        if NavFactory.shared.nmeaDiagnostic
        {
            Syslog.add(origin: .undefined, level: .info, text: "UDP received datacount: \(data.count)")
            Syslog.add(origin: .undefined, level: .info, text: "UDP received data: \(data.hexEncodedString(options: .upperCase))")
            if let datastring = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
            {
                Syslog.add(origin: .undefined, level: .info, text: "UDP received data: \(datastring)")
            }
        }
        
        
        processData(data: data)
    }
```

The *Swift runtime failure: Index out of range* exception happens on the call of `processData(data: data)`

which is defined as

```
 func processData(data: Data)
 {
   // A lot of stuff to process...
 }
```

The diagnostic outputs before work fine.

This happens only rarely and is therefore very hard to trackdown, especially as I have no access to the users setup.

The last log I received shows that the UDP connection was closed about 3 minutes before the crash happened.

Could it be that CocoaAsyncSocket still processes buffered data after the socket closed and this causes some corrupt data ?

Comment: According to this code the crash can only occur while *A lot of stuff to process*. And  it's highly recommended to prefer `.isEmpty` over `.count == 0`

Comment: I see your point about .isEmpty. Didn't knew that would apply to Data as well as String, but in hindsight it seems logical.
But the crash occurs upon calling processData, still within the calling method, not in the called method. At least if I am going to believe BugSnags error reporting.

Comment: In the method call there is no code which can cause a crash. Set the Exception Breakpoint, it shows you the proper location **inside** the method.

Comment: If the exception would happen inside processData, Bugsnag would report it there, wouldn't it? At least that is, what I saw from Bugsnag reporting in the past. Unfortunately I cannot debug this live a it happens only on one single customer system and there only very sporadically. My current thought is corrupted  stack data somehow caused by an unexpected termination of the UDP connection, but I have no idea how to pin it down.